# Nuance of ざんす / ざんしょ as a sentence ender

Tags: nuances, sentence-final-particles

I'm reading Harry Potter And The Goblet Of Fire. In chapter 18, the Rita Skeeter character appears for the first time (it's an obnoxious paparazzi woman) and she uses this sentence ender that I haven't seen before.

Some example sentences:

> すてきざんすわ
> あんなガヤガヤした所にはいたくないざんしょ
> だって、最年少の代表選手ざんしょ....ちょっと味つけにね？

It's probably not terribly important but I'm interested what "flavor" it's supposed to add to her speach. I read somewhere that it is used in anime/manga but I don't watch all that much anime or read manga so I haven't encountered this before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's from old [山の手言葉](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B1%B1%E3%81%AE%E6%89%8B%E8%A8%80%E8%91%89). ざます/ざぁます/ざんす used to be actively used in the past among classy madams in [Yamanote regions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamanote_and_Shitamachi), but today it's used mainly in fiction as role language of snobbish people and nouveau riche (usually middle-aged or older).

> 現在では金持ちや成金、上品ぶった人、あるいはいわゆる「教育ママ」などを表す役割語として使われることがある。

The most famous user of ざます in fiction is probably [Suneo's mother](https://doraemon.fandom.com/wiki/Suneo%27s_mother).